# Characters does not replace in string

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a phone number like this

> +43 0431 15903412

But at my `EditText` this is the input I give

> 431 903412

The only thing I need is to add a 0 before 4 and 15 before 9, is there any regex or simple way of adding this without looping through all the characters in my string and replacing by index ?

I did this to add the +43 0

```
val modifiedPhoneNumber = "+430$phoneNumber"
```

But now I need to add the 15 before 9 and I dont know how

Thanks

Comment: is it space separated ? I mean the phoneNumber

Comment: no, is not, is continuos

Comment: Need more info. Not familiar with this phone number system. Will the user sometimes type the full number that doesn't need to be modified? Will the user sometimes type the 15, but not the +430?

Comment: Does the number has a format that before first three digits add 0 and after, add 15?

Comment: The phone number needs to follow Argentina phone style

Comment: If you know for sure that after 3 characters you need to add "15", you can do this with substring.

"+430${phoneNumber.substring(0, 3)}15${phoneNumber.substring(3, phoneNumber.length())}"

But before this you need to check if phoneNumber has more that 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as i understand you need  +43 0431 15903412 from 431 903412 
>   it can be done as follow using `StringBuilder`

```
 var j = 431903412
        var x = Integer.toString(j)
        x = StringBuilder(x).insert(x.length - 9, "+430").insert(x.length - 6, "15").toString()
        Log.e("Show Updated Strin", x)
```

using this you will get `+43150431903412`